# Como obter o posicionamento do cliente no mapa?

Tags: php, maps, geolocalização, localização

Consigo somente pegar a localização aproximada do cliente, mas haveria uma forma que eu conseguisse localiza-lo em um mapa, com esses dados que possuo?
Consigo apenas dados da localização como Cidade, estado, latitude, longitude etc.
Com esse [site](http://ip-api.com/php/) e esse código:

```
   $query = @unserialize(file_get_contents('http://ip-api.com/php/'.$ip));
    $lat=isset($query['lat'])?$query['lat']:'';
    $lon=isset($query['lon'])?$query['lon']:'';
```

Comment: A resposta é SIM, porque sabemos que há formas de fazer isso :-s . Seja mais especifico, apresente o código e suas dificuldades, para que possamos ajudar.

Comment: A pergunta está pobríssima de detalhes, um conselho, edite e deixe ela o mais claro possível, descrevendo detalhadamente o que você quer. Ou ela pode ser fechada, o tema é interessante, mas a pergunta em si deixou muito a desejar da forma que foi apresentada.

Comment: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple

Answer (score 1):

Sim, é possível exibir os clientes em um mapa, na localização exata, de várias maneiras diferentes.

O que não ficou claro é **se você tem os dados de latitude e longitude** dos seus clientes ou não. Se tiver, tem como fazer.

Se você não tiver estes dois dados, é impossível exibir exatamente onde fica cada cliente.